# Installing django with python error on widows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I seem to get errors when installing django with the following commands. I follow the instructions form the book i am using exactly but get errors. First installing pipenv gave me errors about path and updating the paths in windows manually fixed that.

```
pip3 install pipenv            <---- executes correlty with no errors

pipenv install django ~=3.1.0   <----- get the following errors below
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 194, in install
    do_install(
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2046, in do_install
    pkg_requirement = Requirement.from_line(pkg_line)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 2674, in from_line
    parsed_line = Line(line)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 171, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 1304, in parse
    self.parse_name()
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 1027, in parse_name
    name = self._parse_name_from_line()
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 968, in _parse_name_from_line
    raise RequirementError(
pipenv.vendor.requirementslib.exceptions.RequirementError: Failed parsing requirement from 'C:\\Users\\=3.1.0'
```

any help would be appreciated. I have disabled windows defender just encase it was a internet access isue even though the error does not report as such. I am running all commands through windwos power shell as administrator. I am using python 3.9

I cant seem to find anyone with similar problem online. Would appreciate some help

Thank you

Comment: Please format your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Make new env

```
Mkvirtualenv test
pip install django
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately this did not help. I have already installed virtualenv successfully but cant get django to install. I keep getting the above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just encase anyone is interested in why I was encountering the above error, it was because of the space between django and ~ .

pipenv install django ~=3.1.0  <------ gave me errors

pipenv install django~=3.1.0 <----- everything was fine.